# How can I connect to api when I use useReducer hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

When using redux, what we use to do is create `reducer`, `constants` and `action functions`.
In redux its pretty simple we can write `api calling` method in `action functions` and export them.

But
Now i am testing a new hook call `useReducer`. The advantage of useReducer is that I only need to
passed in `dispatch` to the child component and call the related command Eg: `dispatch({type: 'ADD'})` to make the change works,

So let me show you an example code. Here is the simple reducer

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD":
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
                    task: action.task,
                    completed: false,
                },
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

What this code does is pretty simple. its just **adding another task to the state**. But it only work for local env.

So If let say if i need to add a new task I need to make a post request to `www.TODO.com/addNew`

Where should i write that method `axios.post('www.TODO.com/addNew', newTask).then((res) => ...)`

If I write an separate `function actions`. Passing only `dispatch` which is the `selling point of useReducer` to child will not be work anymore because i also need to export `function actions`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` to make async calls and  update the reducer states on your function component

**Sample**

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialArg); 

//do async calls inside useEffect and update dispatch the updates
useEffect(()=>{
  fetch('example.com')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => dispatch({type: 'ADD', payload: json}) )
},[])
```

Comment: just for clarification. If I want to use this `ADD` feature in other page. I need to write this `useEffect` multiple time right

Comment: yes you need to do the this, if you don't like to type this again create custom hook for it